# Finding nodes ID in communication range of another node in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

How to find nodes IDs in communication range of another node? I set communication range of a node to r=100. I wanted to set all those nodes as one hop neighbors which are in its range. How should i do that in omnet++? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there no one who can help me out?
What should i work on to find the position of nodes and check that whether they are in the range? 
I typed this question here because i'm unable to do that. Don't know why people down rated it :(

Answer (score 0):

Module positions are set in OMNeT++ via [display string tags](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:display-strings). You are looking for the first two components of the `p` tag, which stores modules' positions in a parent module. From these positions, you can derive the modules' distances. For dynamically finding out which modules are in a parent module, refer to the user manual's chapter on [exploring the module hierarchy](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:walking-up-and-down-module-hierarchy).

Comment: Thank you so  much for the response. 
I have tried printing the current location of the node by using the following commands. But it does not show me anything.
cModule *parent = getParentModule();
EV<<parent->getDisplayString().getTagArg("p0",0)<< "\n";
What should i do to find the current position?

Comment: your are calling `getTagArg("p0", 0)` which returns the first component of tag `p0`. You want to investigate the `p` tag instead.

Comment: I have tried now cModule *parent = getParentModule(); EV<<parent->getDisplayString().getTagArg("p",0)<< "\n"; 
Its too not displaying any information.

Comment: Are the simulation modules you are using setting node positions for display in the graphical execution environment of OMNeT++? If you are using The INET Framework, MiXiM, or something similar they are (and they are using the `p` tag). Without knowing which simulation modules, program versions, etc you are using it will be hard to understand what is giving you problems

Comment: I'm not using using any framework INET, MIXIM etc to make the project simple
Whenever i set the p tag in the ned file i can get the position by
    EV<<getDisplayString().getTagArg("p", 0);
    EV<<getDisplayString().getTagArg("p", 1);
i have written the following lines in the ned file
    @display("i=device/cellphone;r=100");
     node0: Class
        { 
        @display("p=20,50");
        }
   node1: Class
    { 
        @display("p=70,100");
    }
    node2: Class
    { 
        @display("p=30,190");
    }
    node3: Class
    { 
        @display("p=120,120");
    }

Comment: I don't believe there is a way of getting a simulation module's position if you haven't configured one.

Comment: Is there any way to find the position without setting it using INET etc?
Please tell me how should i find ids of all those nodes which are in communication range of the current node(the one who tries to send packets)? I'm using send Direct for sending packets.

Comment: I don't want to set the positions of nodes myself, as there would be 100 plus nodes in my project. 
I doing it to find the one hop neighbor ids. 
Can i broadcast hello messages by using sendDirect? or Is there any other simplest way to broadcast message in omnet++?

Comment: Please tell me how to broadcast hello message using sendDirect?